# django rest framework control the permissions of each api url

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want control the permissions of each api url,include methods (post,get,put,delete),how to do?

I tried the code like:

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

METHOD_CHOICES = (
    ('get','get'),
    ('post','post'),
    ('put','put'),
    ('delete','delete')
  )

class ApiPermessions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    apiuri = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=u'授权api')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=0000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u'权限代码')
    choices = MultiSelectField(choices=METHOD_CHOICES)
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly?  Are you trying to set permissions for Django API endpoints based on their HTTP verbs?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom permissions class inside your django-rest-framework app. Refer to [their docs here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

To give you an outline, this would look like a class that defines these permissions:

```
from rest_framework import permissions, exceptions

class CustomUserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
   def has_permission(self, request, view):
       request_method = request.method
       request_user = getattr(request, 'user')

       if request_user:
           # Returns true if the request method is 
           # in the permissions set of the user object
           return request_method in \
               user.api_permissions_set.all().values_list('choices', flat=True)
```

You can define this as the permissions class in your rest framework config, through which it will be applicable on all views automatically.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'CustomUserPermissions',
)
```